# Google Analytics: Import additional data for events

Tags: google-analytics

We frequently import additional data into Google analytics to enrich the data about the page hits. Now we would like to do the same for events (instead of page impression) but are unable to do it. We know the category, action and label of the events we would like to enrich.

We have defined the custom dimension ("manufacturer") with scope "hit". After that, we tried to set up a new data set. But whatever we choose as the data set type, event category, action and label are never offered as options in the data import UI.

Is it possible at all to enrich events? If yes, how can it be achieved?

Comment: IIRC if you sent a custom dimension along with the event you should be able to select the "custom data" dataset and use that as key to import one or more other custom dimensions (which need to be created in the property settings first). To the best of my knowledge you cannot enrich event data directly.